# How to remove an object from ManyToMany relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with ManyToMany relationship.

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, related_name='folders', default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.File
        fields = '__all__'


class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = FileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    file = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.File.objects.all(),
                                          write_only=True, label='File Name')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Folder
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'files', 'file')
```

I am able to add a file object to the folder. I am able to update the name of the folder too. But how do I remove a file object from the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are accessing from files

> file = File.objects.get(query)

Then you can do

> file.folders.remove(folder_object)

Edit:
Your app's urls file:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import folder
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'remove-folder/', folder, name='remove_folder'),
]
```

Your apps views.py:

```
def folder(request):
    file = File.objects.get(query)
    file.folders.remove(folder_object)
    # return appropriate data
```

Comment: how to create a api endpoint to do this? I am not sure where to put this ? is it in serializer or viewsets? can you give an example

Comment: You can put this in your views.py and point your api url to that view.

Comment: This is not DRF.

Comment: Please provide your solution @hassanketabi